# ngrtx router-store selectors can't see router state

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-router-store

I have an ngrx/store app with ngrx/router-store installed. In the application I have three features - two that are "eager" (`auth` and `router`) and one lazy (`admin`). `admin` contains a slice state named `user`.

Despite being eager, the router selectors don't seem to work. The console.warn message, (otherwise very clear and instructional!) doesn't really solve the problem as the feature is clearly declared/defined in the `app.module.ts`:

**app.module.ts**

```
StoreModule.forRoot(
  {
    [AUTH_FEATURE_KEY]: AuthFeature.reducer,
    router: routerReducer,
  },
  {
    metaReducers: !environment.production ? [] : [],
    runtimeChecks: {
      strictActionImmutability: true,
      strictStateImmutability: true,
    },
  }
),
```

**router.selectors.ts**

```
export const getRouterState = createFeatureSelector<RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>>('router');

export const getCurrentRoute = createSelector(
  getRouterState,
  router => {
    console.log('getCurrentRoute', router) // <-- undefined
    return router.state;
  }
);

export const getRouterStateParams = createSelector(
  getCurrentRoute,
  state => state.params
);
```

Then in one of my lazy loaded modules I am combining `getRouterStateParams` with entities:

**user.selectors.ts**

```
export const getUserFromRouteParam = createSelector(
  selectEntities,
  fromRouter.getRouterStateParams,
  (entities, params) => {
    console.log(entities, params)
    return entities[params['id']]
  }
)
```

and this is where the error happens.

[image]

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong, or is it some kind of a race condition?

### Update

What I tried so far:

- setting `StoreModule.forFeature()` for each eager reducer separately, and `StoreModule.forRoot({})`
- setting `initialNavigation: 'enabled'` - this only causes the route slice to appear right off the bat (normally, the reducer kicks in only after the first navigation event), but it doesn't rectify `undefined`s coming from selectors
- not using `CustomSerializer`, instead base on the default serializer and factory delivered `getSelectors()` - all the selectors that I am interested in, for url, params and queryParams - returned `undefined` too
- different settings for `navigationActionTiming`
- every possible tip mentioned in [this twin-similar issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/835), including the explicit `initialState` object

Comment: Do you actually import StoreRouterConnectingModule?

Comment: @MikeOne yes, absolutely, providing a custom serializer to it; and the import statement is in place too :)

Comment: Hmm.. strange. The routerstore actually provides its own selectors as well. Do those work?

Comment: These selectors are useless when you use a custom serializer because the custom state structure is then usually different. However, out of curiosity, will try to disable the serializer and revert to the factory setup

Comment: For the router you should use import { getSelectors } from '@ngrx/router-store'; export const {
  selectCurrentRoute, // select the current route
  selectFragment, // select the current route fragment
  selectQueryParams, // select the current route query params
  selectQueryParam, // factory function to select a query param
  selectRouteParams, // select the current route params
  selectRouteParam, // factory function to select a route param
  selectRouteData, // select the current route data
  selectUrl // select the current url
} = getSelectors(); NOT a custom selector

Comment: @user3887366 as per [their docs](https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/selectors): _The getSelectors method works with the routerReducer provided by @ngrx/router-store. If you use a custom serializer, you'll need to provide your own selectors._

Comment: Sorry always used a custom serializer ^^